# Django 2.1.2 Password reset auth view: Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-authentication

I am having a problem with the passeord reset system.
The code is as below. When I enter the respective URL into the browser address directly it shows the expected Django forms/pages.
However if I fill an email address and hit enter/click the link, I get the "Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name." error at line 6 in password_reset_email.html.
But I have included the uid64! and the token!
Also, when I deliberately use an incorrect email address I get the "Reverse for 'password_reset_done' not found. 'password_reset_done' is not a valid view function or pattern name." error.

I cannot see from the django documentation, other similar questions on this site, or various guides, what the obvious simple step is that I must have missed.

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from . import views

app_name = 'users'
urlpatterns = [
    path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password_reset/confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password_reset/complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Django does not use a namespace when reversing the password reset urls.py. You can stop the error by removing `app_name='users'` from your `urls.py`.

Alternatively, you can configure the password reset view to use the namespace:"

```
path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(success_url=reverse_lazy('users:password_reset_done')), name='password_reset'),
```

This will fix the immediate error, but you'll find that you need to make several other changes to fix similar errors. Removing `app_name='users'` is more straight forward.

Comment: Trying to use the success_url method gives a TypeError: PasswordResetDoneView() received an invalid keyword 'success_url'. as_view only accepts arguments that are already attributes of the class

Comment: removing the app name does work, there were other url that I am defining within that that file. Seperating them out has succeded. Thanks ever so much for the help.

Comment: That error is from `PasswordResetDoneView` -- my answer said you had to change `PasswordResetView`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! I obviously need coffee. Thank you ever so much.

Answer (score 0):

When you define `app_name` you should specify it also for reverse.
Use `users:password_reset_done` instead of `password_reset_done`

Check [reversing-namespaced-urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls) for more details.