# Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found when using PasswordResetDoneView with a custom app_name

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-urls, django-authentication

I keep getting this error:

Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

The following is my code so far:

**urls.py**

```
app_name='stock'
urlpatterns = [   
 path('reset_password/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='stock/password_reset.html'),
         name='reset_password'),

    path('reset_password_sent/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='stock/password_reset_sent.html'),
         name='password_reset_done'),

    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='stock/password_reset_form.html'),
         name='password_reset_confirm'),

    path('reset_password_complete/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='stock/password_reset_done.html'),
         name='password_reset_complete'),

]
```

**Template.py**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div>
    <h3>Password Reset</h3>
       <p>Please enter you new password twice so we can verify you type correctly.</p>
     <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <input type="submit" name="Update Password " />
  </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: you should provide your template code also

Comment: The code you show seems to indicate that the name of the url is "stock:password_reset_confirm", because you're name spacing it. Somewhere in your code you're calling `reverse` (or `{% url %}`) on "password_reset_confirm" without the "stock".

Comment: @bmons i update my question with template code.

Comment: as dirkgroten mentioned, check all your links where you might have forgot to add the name space 'stock'

Comment: @bmons and dirkgroten according to me, there is no file where i add  the link for this

Comment: usually forget password is on login page, check it there, or in home page footer

Comment: that's  working  perfectly, there is just one link which is that `    <a href="{% url 'stock:reset_password' %}">Forgot Password?</a>`

Comment: thank you @Alasdair and also everyone for helping ...

Comment: It's the `PasswordResetDoneView` which is trying to reverse the namespace. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52932303/django-2-1-2-password-reset-auth-view-reverse-for-password-reset-confirm-not) for how to fix it. IIRC, you'll also get an error from `PasswordResetConfirmView` unless you make a similar change. It might be easier to remove app_name='stock' (or move those URL patterns to a urls.py without a namespace).